# Set title FBSDKLoginButton not work

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm trying to change the title of FBSDKLoginButton but not work...

```
[self.button setTitle:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!

Comment: This is extremely likely not allowed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the default title of FBSDKLoginButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885962/change-the-default-title-of-fbsdkloginbutton)

Comment: @buxik his question is not a duplicate of the one you linked to because Juan's question was asked before the one you linked to was asked.  If you comment about possible duplicates, it's best to check dates!

Comment: @jungledev anyway I added an answer there :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of modifying the Facebook SDK(not recommended), you can add a custom button, and set title/color on it.

`FBSDKLoginManager` can be used if FB Login is handled via custom button.

For more info, your can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32309831/1673045).