# Change the default title of FBSDKLoginButton

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

The question is really specific.

Is there a way to change the default english title "Log in with Facebook" for the FBSDKLoginButton class?

Inside the class implementation I've seen that LoginButton.LogInLong is the key for the string but I had no luck adding the key to my own internationalisation file. Also I've tried to use the title attribute for UIButton on the storyboard but this didn't work.

I've found this two methods inside the implementation file of the class:

```
- (NSString *)_longLogInTitle
{
  return NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"LoginButton.LogInLong", @"FacebookSDK", [FBSDKInternalUtility bundleForStrings],
                                           @"Log in with Facebook",
                                           @"The long label for the FBSDKLoginButton when the user is currently logged out");
}


- (NSString *)_shortLogInTitle
{
  return NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"LoginButton.LogIn", @"FacebookSDK", [FBSDKInternalUtility bundleForStrings],
                                           @"Log in",
                                           @"The short label for the FBSDKLoginButton when the user is currently logged out");
}
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You can extend FBSDKLoginButton and set title by override 'setTitle' function (Swift version):

```
import Foundation
import FBSDKLoginKit

class MyFBLoginButton: FBSDKLoginButton {

    override func setTitle(_ title: String?, for state: UIControlState) {
        super.setTitle("YOUR CUSTOM FACEBOOK TITLE", forState: state)
    }
}
```

And next use your own facebook button class in storyboard or add button programitically

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to change the default english title for the FBSDKLoginButton class, as shown below:

```
FBSDKLoginButton *loginButton = [[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
NSAttributedString *string = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Your custom title"];
[loginButton setAttributedTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use own button for facebook login and put the code below in your button touch-down action

```
- (IBAction)buttonLoginWithFacebookTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeClear];
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email",@"public_profile"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    } else if (result.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"error: Facebook Login Process Cancelled");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"signed auth token - %@ \n %@",result.token,[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]);
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing this. But I want the button rounded, and with the FB logo on the left. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @halbano you can set button layer border.

Comment: I can't understand your approach completely I think.

Comment: means, you can create a button same as facebook button with custom title