# How to get user info after login with FBSDKLoginKit in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, fbsdk

I have created a button:

```
let button = FBSDKLoginButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50))
button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends"]
view.addSubview(button)
```

then tap it and make some things to login. Where do I receive data after login? How to get access to them?

**NOTE**

The question is about `FBSDKLoginKit`, not `Facebook-ios-sdk`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple implementation for received `token` and `userID` after login:

```
func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {

    if error != nil {
        print("error")
    } else if result.isCancelled {
        print("cancelled")
    } else {
        print("token: \(result.token.tokenString)")
        print("user_id: \(result.token.userID)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func returnFBUserData()
{
    let graphRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"id, first_name, last_name"])
    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            let uniqueId = result.valueForKey("id") as! NSString!
            let firstName = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! NSString!
            let lastName = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! NSString!
            print(uniqueId) // This works
            print(firstName)
            print(lastName)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implementing the [`loginButton:didCompleteWithResult:error:`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate) delegate method of `FBSDKLoginKit` should give you access to the login result, as follows:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = FBSDKLoginButton(frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 300, 50))
        button.delegate = self
        button.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends"]
        view.addSubview(button)
    }

    func loginButton(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWithResult result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) {
        // do stuff with result, get token, userId...
    }

    func loginButtonDidLogOut(loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {

    }
}
```

Comment: what property of that object is the one that I need?:)

Comment: Still the question is, how to get user info from result? Where is it assigned to? I asked about public profile and user friends. Where do I get them from?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a graph request to fetch user data. You can get the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32309831/1673045).